# php css/js minifier?

Tags: php, javascript, css, compression

I have a custom loader for my css and javascript functions.

as such.

when I am ready I have a list of css and another of javascript files.

I am looking for a way that I can then call a function and it will output a path to a compressed and combined css and js file.

so.

something like

```
load::css('master');
load::css('links');
load::css('buttons');
load::css();
```

(calling load:css() without any params should generate the minified css link)

What classes do you suggest for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your aim correctly Php Speedy may help you. Check it out: http://aciddrop.com/php-speedy/ .

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work quite the way you want, but I've found it pretty useful to use minify (http://code.google.com/p/minify/), then have a separate class (I use Zend Framework's headStyle view helper) collect all the css files I need, then build a single css/JS link that I include.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that, however My issue comes as, almost every page on my site uses a different combination of css and javascript files, hence, normally averaging 7 files each. I am hoping to be able to just call a minify class, and it would generate me a css/js file name based on the files. it would use some sort of alogrithm to ensure that the filename is based off the file contents and, if the js/css file exists, return is, else, create it then return it.

Comment: I had something that was pretty similar. The way minify works is that you can include a url that's something like http://yoursite.com/minify/?foo.css,bar.css,foobar.css as your CSS, and it will generate a minified CSS file. I had around 15 files, and it got pretty slow, but it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a "build" shell script for javascript and css, which I the javascript from the server, and then compress it using YUICompressor.

This wouldn't be a run-time compression like you're looking for, it'd be more of a one-time build process you do when you publish your site. My javascript is mostly static, though, so I can get away with this.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /webroot/js
wget -nc -O filename.premin.js http://localhost/js/filename.src.js
java -jar yuicompressor.jar --line-break=200 -o filename.min.js filename.src.js
rm filename.premin.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem you're trying to solve is that you have "too many" JS/CSS files being served.

By looking for a way to merge them together, you're only compounding your problem by inventing new files that must be delivered to your clients.

Instead, learn about HTTP caching, and use it: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/